# UNPIVOT columns using SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, crosstab, unpivot, vba

I am pulling another workbook containing a table that has Columns like ItemCreationDate, and most columns (total 28 such columns) that begin with the word "Global" in them. i want to

1. pull these "Global" columns (including ItemCreationDate) into an SQL recordset, 
   add a new Column called Old/New and then
2. UNPIVOT them i.e. Stack them up one above the other and
3. in the next column, list their Column items along with their Counts.
4. Their Counts are derived based on the ItemCreationDate where any date <2015 is OLD & >=2015 is NEW
5. Final Output should be as shown in Output sheet.

i have attached a [Sample.xlsx](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=70DD8A43F234706D!918&authkey=!ADSEBHgUuoW8L0A&ithint=file%2Cxlsx) file where i have shown how i have to arrive at the Output tab starting from the Data sheet. This Data sheet is actually the input that i want to pull into a recordset and spit out the table as shown in the Output sheet.  I don't want to create Pivot table as its cumbersome and the data is quite a lot, and i want an alternative SQL approach, wherein i can quickly aggregate the data and insert it into sheet in one go.

i am not using SQL Server, so cannot use the UNPIVOT command or Dynamic SQL to loop thru all the "Global" columns.

Basically i want to form a correct SQL string something like....

```
Dim arrSQL as variant
......
......
RS.Filter="Like Global*"
......
arrSQL = JOIN(RS.Fields, vbCr)

strSQL = "SELECT [arrSQL], IIF(YEAR([ITEM CREATION DATE])>=YEAR(DATE())-1,""NEW"",""OLD"") AS [New/Old]  from [Data$] GROUP BY...."
strSQL = strSQL & " UNION ALL " & vbcr & _
strSQL = strSQL & " ......
```

Now, run SQL on same recordset to reduce the columns and get required data format....
i know the above is not quite correct, but something on those lines so that i can get the correct output as show in the Output tab.

can anyone help quickly?

Edits for @a_horse_with_no_name :

see the screenshots of the sample file:

1. Data sheet:
   this is actually a table from an input workbook that i want to pull in a Recordset. See the various "Global" column headings and their items that i want to unpivot.

[image]

2. This are the 2 intermediate sheets "New" & "Old" i have to create everytime (that i want to get rid of actually). any items found in 2015 or later are put in New, whereas rest are put in Old.

[image]

[image]

3. [image]
4. JFYI, the formulae that are manually used in Output columns are :

C column (New):

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(New!$A:$D,0,MATCH($A2,New!$1:$1,0)),Output!$B2)
```

D Column (Old):

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Old!$A:$D,0,MATCH($A2,Old!$1:$1,0)),Output!$B2)
```

E Column (% New):

```
=Output!C2/SUM(C$2:C$6)
```

F Column (% Old):

```
=Output!D2/SUM(D$2:D$6)
```

G Column (Index):

```
=IF(AND(E2<=0,F2<=0),0,IF(AND(E2>0,F2>0),E2/F2,1))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which DBMS **are** you using?

Comment: i am only using Excel VBA with ADO, not Access or SQL Server. I want to pull the table of another input workbook into a ADODB recordset and create the output format. don't know how to do the same.

Comment: If you want to execute a SQL statement you must be using _some_ DBMS.

Comment: [ADOdb](http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php) seems to be an abstraction layer for PHP, not a database system.

Comment: i am sorry, i did not get you. Where does PHP come in? i am using Excel VBA with ADO to pull in excel table from another workbook. Have you seen the Sample.xlsx workbook i have shared? The "Data" sheet is actually the table that i want to pull into a recordset and then spit out the final Output as shown in the Output sheet.

Comment: did you click on the link in my comment? That's the first hit when you search for adodb. Apart from that: I will **not** download a binary file from an unknown source. And I guess with all the ransom ware that is disttributed through Ofifice files other people won't either

Comment: its an xlsx file without any code. how do you want me to send you the file. regarding ADOdb, i really didn't know of such a site or such an abstraction layer for PHP. i meant [ADO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX_Data_Objects), which is actually a wrapper for OLEDB

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , see edits for you in my original post, where i have shared screenshots of the sheets for your perusal. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can run SQL queries in MS Excel using the [Jet/ACE SQL Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) (a Windows .dll file) which is the very data store that MS Access is connected to by default. And as such, this technology equipped on all PCs is not restricted to any one Office/Windows program.

Consider the following Excel VBA macro (if using Excel on PC) that connects to ACE via ADO running a union of three aggregate SQL queries (*GLOBAL VIT/CALC*, *GLOBAL FLAVOURS*, *GLOBAL FLAVOUR GROUP*) and conditional New and Old counts/percentages. The latter percentage column pair required subqueries.

For proper setup, do the following:

1. Make sure  `Item Creation Date` is in MM-DD-YYYY (US-based) or DD-MM-YYYY (non-US based) date formats which is not how above screenshot or file has date field currently formatted.

   `Sub FormatDates()
       For i = 2 To 2083
           Range("A" & i) = CDate(Range("A" & i))
       Next i
   End Sub`
2. Run macro in a different workbook than the one holding the data. Below assumes data workbook holds source information in worksheet named `Data`.
3. In query-running workbook, create a blank worksheet named `RESULTS` which will be populated with query output including column headers.

**VBA** Script *(two connections available Driver (commented out) and Provider versions)*

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunSQL()
    Dim cols As Object, datawbk As Workbook, datawks As Worksheet
    Dim lastcol As Integer, i As Integer, j As Variant, output As Variant

    Set cols = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set datawbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\To\Data\Workbook.xlsx;")
    Set datawks = datawbk.Worksheets("Data")
    lastcol = datawks.Cells(7, datawks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 2 To lastcol
         cols.Add CStr(i - 1), datawks.Cells(1, i).Value
    Next i

    datawbk.Close False
    Set datawks = Nothing
    Set datawbk = Nothing

    output = DataCapture(cols)

End Sub

Function DataCapture(datacols As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim classSQL As String, itemSQL As String, grpSQL As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer, fld As Object, d As Variant, lastrow As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' Hard code database location and name '
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Data\Workbook.xlsx;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Data\Workbook.xlsx;" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES IMEX=1;"";"

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION '
    conn.Open strConnection

    For Each d In datacols.keys
        strSQL = " SELECT '" & datacols(d) & "' AS [COLUMN], [Data$].[" & datacols(d) & "] AS ITEMS," _
                    & "   SUM(IIF(Year([Item Creation Date]) >= Year(Date()) - 1, 1, 0)) AS NEW," _
                    & " " _
                    & "   SUM(IIF(Year([Item Creation Date]) < Year(Date()) - 1, 1, 0)) AS OLD," _
                    & " " _
                    & "   ROUND(SUM(IIF(Year([Item Creation Date]) >= Year(Date()) - 1, 1, 0)) / " _
                    & "   (SELECT Count(*) FROM [Data$] AS sub" _
                    & "    WHERE Year(sub.[Item Creation Date]) >= Year(Date()) - 1),2) AS NEWPCT," _
                    & " " _
                    & "   ROUND(SUM(IIF(Year([Item Creation Date]) < Year(Date()) - 1, 1, 0)) / " _
                    & "   (SELECT Count(*) FROM [Data$] AS sub" _
                    & "    WHERE Year(sub.[Item Creation Date]) < Year(Date()) - 1),2) AS OLDPCT" _
                    & " FROM [Data$]" _
                    & " GROUP BY [Data$].[" & datacols(d) & "]"

        ' OPEN RECORDSET '
        rst.Open strSQL, conn

        ' COLUMN HEADERS '
        If d = 1 Then
            i = 0
            Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A1").Activate
            For Each fld In rst.Fields
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = fld.Name
                i = i + 1
            Next fld
        End If

        ' DATA ROWS '
        lastrow = Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Worksheets("RESULTS").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A" & lastrow + 1).CopyFromRecordset rst

        rst.Close
    Next d

    conn.Close

    MsgBox "Successfully processed SQL query!", vbInformation
    Exit Function

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Function
End Function
```

**Output**

[image: Excel SQL Query Output Screenshot]

Comment: if you see my original post, i have mentioned there are approx 28 such Global columns whose names i may not know. How do i adjust the SQL Query to account for them without knowing their names? Also, i followed your instructions and am getting the following error: [err1](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=70DD8A43F234706D!920&authkey=!AE6Pwul2wsPArq0&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG), [err2](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=70DD8A43F234706D!921&authkey=!AIyx2cmew6Te3Zw&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG). What could be wrong?

Comment: i changed the connection string to 
        strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='" & strPath & strFile & "';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES IMEX=1;"";"

also replaced the IIF date with.......

    IIF(YEAR([ITEM CREATION DATE]) >= YEAR(DATE())-1
and
    IIF(YEAR([ITEM CREATION DATE]) < YEAR(DATE())-1

Recordset gets created, but empty. Now getting error:

    9 - Subscript out of range

Comment: but when i take a debug.Print of the sqlstring and run it in access over the same data table, the query returns the data. what could be wrong? Also, can the percentages be formatted in SQL to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Interesting. I added your same connection string and `IIF()` logic with no issues. See update. Possibly you are using a fuller workbook different from your posted OneDrive version or different OS environment. I use Windows 10/64-bit/Office 2013. Though both use same backend SQL engine, an MS Access UI query allows [VBA functions](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/) not all available with a Jet/ACE ODBC query.

Comment: As for the 28 columns, you can add another recordset which loops through distinct column values and iteratively pass into aggregate query recordset. Are they laid out in columns or rows of another table? Also, why are you doing this work in Excel when you have Access available where such query processing is more native and fluid (no ADO)?

Comment: how can i modify the SQL query so that i can run it on the data, irrespective of knowing how many or which Global columns would be there? See, there are Global columns as well as other unwanted columns. for sake of example, i just included 3 Global columns.
is there a way to write the SQL query in a loop by identifying and adding the global columns and forming the query?

Comment: the input data to the Excel tool comes to us in the form of xlsx file, secondly and the most obvious reason is most users of the tool, don't have access installed on their systems.

Comment: the Global columns are in the first row of the Data sheet table (input file) as Headers. As my example showed and you demonstrated via code, all Global columns are to be stacked one below the other along with the count of their items.

Comment: i copy pasted your code and ran it on the sample, it finally worked! Now only the issue of getting all the Global columns in SQL string remains.... :)

Comment: See update where new macro obtains all header columns from data workbook and passes a dictionary of column names into the looped aggregate query function. No longer a union query but data is stacked on top of each other and in order of Global columns.

Comment: Cool. actually i was trying to write code following your earlier advice of using a ADO recordset to search for columns starting with "Global", as that way i wouldnt have to open the wieldy huge workbook (takes time to open on my system). Not successful....

Comment: For Each fld in RS.Fields
      if instr(1, fld.Name, lcase("Global"))>0 then 
            coll.add cstr(fld.name),cstr(fld.name)
      end if 
Next fld

Comment: Also, could you explain why you have removed UNION from the SQL query loop?

Comment: No need for a union with long sql concatenation if you are looping. Plus, Jet/ACE has a limit of selects in union. By the way, any PC user can connect directly to the .mdb/.accdb file with ADO regardless if MSAccess.exe program is installed. And yes, change code to suit needs. Please accept answer if it helped.

Comment: thanks a bunch. the code works like a charm. :) Yes, i think there is a limit of 45-46 unions, right? One question before you go...Why do the columns especially the percentage columns show up as General format and not round up to 2 decimals for all? Can this be changed or do i need to format the columns once the data falls into the worksheet?

Comment: Yes around there depending on complexity. General Number is default Excel formatting. Simply format entire columns with `NumberFormat = "#,###.00"` at the end.

Comment: hi @Parfait , when i step thru the code, at point "for each d in datacols.keys, it adds a new blank key to the dict set, because of which at last key, the sql query returns an error as there is really no field....how to solve this?